# normalize variable as proportion of maximum - minimum

Tags: r

I'm trying to normalize the variable by using normalized = `30 * (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))` to 0-30 scale.

In python it would be:

```
new_escore = esg_funds['Portfolio Environmental Score'].apply(lambda x: 30*(x-esg_funds['Portfolio Environmental Score'].min())/(esg_funds['Portfolio Environmental Score'].max()-esg_funds['Portfolio Environmental Score'].min()))
```

`esg_funds` is my data, and `'Portfolio Environmental Score'` is the variable.

How do I use `apply()` function here?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. [Requests for code translation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296119/is-how-do-i-convert-code-from-this-language-to-this-language-too-broad) are off topic. Forget about the python code, describe what you need to accomplish in R as it's own task.

Comment: Think of a `lambda` as just a function with no name. Thus, make a function in R and provide it the data it needs to compute the `new_score` then pass that data in, voila!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `*apply()` thanks to R's vectorized operations. Instead you can do:

```r
new_escore <- 30 * (
    esg_funds[['Portfolio Environmental Score']] - min(esg_funds[['Portfolio Environmental Score']])
  ) / (
    max(esg_funds[['Portfolio Environmental Score']] - min(esg_funds[['Portfolio Environmental Score']]))
  )
```

Or more succinctly,

```r
normalize <- function(x) 30 * (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))

new_escore <- normalize(esg_funds[['Portfolio Environmental Score']])
```

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, although it's not used here, the R equivalent to `lambda x: x + 1` would be `\(x) x + 1`.

Comment: ok that's so helpful! thank you!